# How convert type received by Reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I build mouse and keyboard recorder for my program. I write all user events and save in serializable object. Information about mouse and keyboard events I get from other program part with protected fields.

That's why for getting values I use reflection like this:

```
foreach (var item in events)
{
    // Get all protected fields by reflection for EventArgs. 
    var allProps = item.EventArgs.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).OrderBy(pi => pi.Name).ToList();
}
```

After this I saved all in serialized object like this.

```
string MouseButton = Convert.ToString(allProps[0].GetValue(item.EventArgs));
```

But now I found out, that I should use mouse and keyboard simulator. It works fine, but works only with `enum MouseButton` and Key types. (something like this)

```
public enum MouseButton
{
    Left = 0x2,
    Right = 0x8,
    Middle = 0x20
}

public static void MouseDown(MouseButtons button)
{
    switch (button)
    {
        case MouseButtons.Left:
            MouseDown(MouseButton.Left);
            break;
        case MouseButtons.Middle:
            MouseDown(MouseButton.Middle);
            break;
        case MouseButtons.Right:
            MouseDown(MouseButton.Right);
            break;
    }
}
```

How I can convert my `string MouseButton` type to `enum MouseButton` type for mouse simulator?

P.S. i tried get right type for `allProps`, but it always return `object` type for me, not real events type.

Comment: Thank you for note. I ```Enym.TryParse```, but sometimes ```allProps[0].GetValue(item.EventArgs)``` equal to ```null``` and parse can't convert ```bool``` to ```string```. I tried different wrapper if end etc for ```null``` chacked, but can't build program with this type problem(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you will want to use the `Enum.Parse` function to convert your `string MouseButton` name into the associated enum value. This will generate an enum value matching the string provided to the name of the vaule.

```
string mouseButtonVal = Convert.ToString(allProps[0].GetValue(item.EventArgs));
MouseButton button = (MouseButton) Enum.Parse(typeof(MouseButton), mouseButtonVal);
```